# Display img element without having to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, image

I need help to display a img element without
having to refresh the page to see the content.

```
<script>      
   function init() {
       $('#pictureBox').attr('src', picture);
   }
</script>

<body onload="init();">
    <img id="pictureBox" src=""></img>
</body>
```

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: What does not work? Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: And what's the `picture` variable? Is it even defined?

Comment: The question regards the problem of loading the image content to the screen before displaying it. I wonder if this could be done in a effecient manner so that i would see the image content instead of having to update the page.

I thought the picture variable was of no interest but if you want to know the variable information here it goes:

var picture = http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=59.332839,18.083389&zoom=15&size=480x800&sensor=false;

Which is a googlemaps picture. And yes the variable is certainly defined since i see the content when refreshing.
I do not have fiddle

Comment: Thank you guys for providing fast and accurate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `preload` the picture first(This cause the picture to be shown immediately), Then you can use the picture dynamically.

```
<script>
   //preloading...
   var mypic = new Image();
   mypic.src = picture;

   $(window).load(function(){
       $('#pictureBox').attr('src', picture);
   });      
</script>

<body>
    <img id="pictureBox" src="" />
</body>
```

Note that in `html5` standard a `img` tag can not have a empty property `src`

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery instead, code will be like this

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">     
        var picture = 'blabla/testimage.jpg';
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#pictureBox').attr('src', picture);
        });
       </script>
     <head/>

        <body>
            <img id="pictureBox" src=""/>
        </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: img tag is self closing <img id="PictureBox" src="" />